# Entity Framework 6 use SQLite dynamic typing

Tags: sqlite, entity-framework, entity-framework-6, .net-4.0, system.data.sqlite

I want to map properties of different types to same column (SQLite allows that), but it fails on EdmModel validation. This setup works if I skip `throw` with debugger, but how can I get around this programmatically?

```
System.Data.Entity.Core.MappingException: Schema specified is not valid. Errors: 
(22,12) : error 2019: Member Mapping specified is not valid.
 The type 'Edm.Int32[...]' of member 'my2F1' in type 'MyOp2' is not compatible with 'SQLite.nvarchar[...]' of member 'Prop1' in type 'Schema.ResumableOperation'.
(23,12) : error 2019: Member Mapping specified is not valid.
 The type 'Edm.String[...]' of member 'my2F2' in type 'MyOp2' is not compatible with 'SQLite.int[...]' of member 'Prop2' in type 'Schema.ResumableOperation'.
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Mapping.StorageMappingItemCollection.Init(EdmItemCollection edmCollection, StoreItemCollection storeCollection, IEnumerable`1 xmlReaders, IList`1 filePaths, Boolean throwOnError)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Mapping.StorageMappingItemCollection..ctor(EdmItemCollection edmCollection, StoreItemCollection storeCollection, IEnumerable`1 xmlReaders)
   at System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration.Edm.DbDatabaseMappingExtensions.ToStorageMappingItemCollection(DbDatabaseMapping databaseMapping, EdmItemCollection itemCollection, StoreItemCollection storeItemCollection)
   at System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration.Edm.DbDatabaseMappingExtensions.ToMetadataWorkspace(DbDatabaseMapping databaseMapping)
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.CodeFirstCachedMetadataWorkspace.Create(DbDatabaseMapping databaseMapping)
   at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbModel.Compile()
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.CreateModel(LazyInternalContext internalContext)
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.RetryLazy`2.GetValue(TInput input)
```

---

```cs
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder builder)
{
    Type[] types = new []{typeof(MyOp1), typeof(MyOp2)}; // discovered dynamically from all loaded assemblies
    foreach (var type in types)
        builder.RegisterEntityType(type);

    builder.Types().Where(t => typeof(ResumableOperation).IsAssignableFrom(t)).Configure(c =>
    {
        c.ToTable(nameof(ResumableOperation))
         .HasKey(nameof(ResumableOperation.MyId));

        foreach (var pi in c.ClrType.GetProperties(BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.DeclaredOnly))
        {
            var attr = pi.GetCustomAttribute<PersistedPropertyAttribute>(inherit: true);
            if (attr != null)
            {
                c.Property(pi)
                 .HasColumnName("Prop" + attr.ColumnNumber);
            }
        }
    });
}
```

```cs
public abstract class ResumableOperation { public int MyId { get; set; } }

class MyOp1 : ResumableOperation
{
    [PersistedProperty1] public string my1F1 { get; set; } // maps to Prop1
    [PersistedProperty2] public int my1F2 { get; set; } // maps to Prop2
}
class MyOp2 : ResumableOperation
{
    [PersistedProperty1] public int my2F1 { get; set; } // maps to Prop1
    [PersistedProperty2] public string my2F2 { get; set; } // maps to Prop2
}
```

EntityFramework Version="6.4.4"

Private reflection solutions are acceptable.

Comment: Use TPH inheritance.

Comment: @GertArnold I am using TPH, but want fixed number of columns in db.
In classical TPH each new property in derived class changes db schema.

Comment: Are you sure? `RegisterEntityType` doesn't allow any customization, but OK, maybe EF still interprets it as TPH with discriminator and all. Anyway, what you want isn't possible. 
EF doesn't support it. Also, there's no guarantee that the property types match. It would be a fragile setup.

Comment: @GertArnold SQLite doesn't enforce type of value stored in cell https://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html and it absolutely ok, if they doesn't match with column definition. It actually works if I skip throw statement deep in ef internals with debugger.